# How can I most effectively use the Kairos "activate" ability?

Tags: dragonvale

I finally finished my Kairos summoning perch, and now I have the "Activate" ability.  What exactly does it do, and how can I use it most effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [DragonVale wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Kairos):

> Activate: Kairos can be activated once every four days using the "Activate" button. Upon activation, activities in the park that require time to complete will be accelerated by six hours.
>
> Ability to give gems to friends and the Colosseum are not accelerated.

Some tips to make best use of this ability:

- Be sure to have a full hatchery and both the Breeding Cave and EBI active.  For maximum benefit, you'd want all of these to have more than 6 hours left (each egg, each breeding pair).
- Fill your farms with Pumpermelons or Dragon Fruit, or a similar long grow time treat.  Especially if you don't yet have the Huge Treat Farm this will be a nice bonus.
- Harvest coins from all habitats.  Especially for the lower capacity habitats, this may save you from hitting the cap once you activate the ability.
- Check the timer on the Kairos pedestal before spending gems to accelerate something.  With such a long cool down, you may easily forget about him - and he's free!

Answer (score 0):

Well the power of Karios speeds up stuff, like breeding, farming... it speeds up everything.
(I don't think that it effect coin production in habitats though.)

Comment: Remember to include as much information as possible! Also, any sources that were used.

Comment: Hi Brandon, welcome to Arqade!  We're a little different than some sites in that we try to make answers that are well sourced and complete.  Try to site sources where possible, and try to provide answers that completely answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

It does speed up the coliseum, I just started a coliseum tournament then I activated Kairos and it went from 24 hours to 18 hours.

Comment: Unless there is a recent change I am not aware of, this is incorrect: ["The Colosseum, incomplete quests (started prior to completion of Kairos), and the ability to give gems to friends or collect party hats are not accelerated."](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Kairos)